# .NET 4.0 application throws ApplicationException when started from another .NET 4.0 (C#) application

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, mutex, process.start

1. Why does a 3rd-party application behave differently if it is launched from within a command shell than it does when launched from within a C# application using `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("ThirdPartyApp.exe");`?
2. Is there a way to launch an application within C# so that it behaves *exactly* like when it is launched from the command shell?

**Details:**
I have a 3rd-party .NET 4.0 application (no source code available) installed and running on my PC. It comes with web services running in IIS. I have written a C# application that uses SOAP messages to call these web services. (Both applications are installed and running on the same PC.) If the 3rd-party app is running prior to launching my app, I'm able to communicate with it without a problem. If the 3rd-party app is not running prior to launching my app, I want to be able to start it. I tried the following code:

```
if (!System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses().Select(rec => rec.ProcessName).Contains("ThirdPartyApp"))
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("ThirdPartyApp.exe");
}
```

If I then try to access the web service through my SOAP client:

```
using (var soapClient = new ThirdPartyAppSoapClient())
{
    soapClient.SomeWebService();
}
```

on the call to `SomeWebService`, the 3rd-party app throws the following exception:

```
2013-02-18 19:43:33,884 [17] ERROR ThirdPartyApp.Manager Error Exception Caught
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Pro
gram Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\ThirdPartyDependen
cy.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServ
er\10.0\ThirdPartyDependency.dll'
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String cod
eBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark&
stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppre
ssSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName as
semblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntr
ospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Ev
idence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm,
Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks, StackCrawlMark& stackM
ark)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile)
   at ...

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\M
icrosoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure lo
gging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fus
ion!EnableLog].


Unhandled Exception: System.ApplicationException: Object synchronization method
was called from an unsynchronized block of code.
   at System.Threading.Mutex.ReleaseMutex()
   at ...
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, C
ontextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, C
ontextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

I am able to call `SomeWebService` just fine if the 3rd-party application was already running before I started my application, so I find it hard to believe there are missing dependencies; but to humor this 3rd-party app, I copied the missing files into the specified folder to see if that would fix the problem. The first error message about a missing dependency then changes to an InvalidCastException, but the second error message (`System.ApplicationException: Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.`) still appears and remains unchanged.

Any help on understanding what I'm doing wrong, and how I can get this 3rd-party app to behave the same regardless of whether it is launched from inside a C# app or outside, will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may have something to do with the user context your application is running in, for example if you run your app as an administrator `Process.Start` will attempt to start the process in the same context.

And please, post the contents of `InvalidCastException`

Comment: You were exactly right. Apparently, my 3rd-party app depends heavily on what the working directory is when it is launched. Setting this parameter in the ProcessStartInfo solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, glad to help you out! :)